# How does tag completion suggestion work?

Tags: discussion, tags

I find tags completion suggestion window pops up fast when you start typing characters in the *Tags* field.

Is the tag list (for completion) stored in client side? (as something like JavaScript variable)
If so how do Stack Overflow send the new tag-list if new tags are added?

Comment: c.c Are you unfamiliar with ajax?

Comment: I thought SO's was faster than other sites' similar feature. and wondered if it was kept in client-side.

Comment: SO has hundreds, if not thousands of tags.  To keep such a list client side would be impossible, in my opinion.  That's quite a lot of data.

Comment: @Eugene it's faster thanks to cache. They don't perform SQL query for each letter typed but rather search in-memory cache, probably highly optimized as well which makes it so fast.

Comment: On second thought, there are unlimited number of query strings(as a key) to cache.. ex) m/mi/mic/micr/micro/... Is that ok? Can you elaborate how the caching would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type anything in the tags input box, AJAX request is being sent. For example:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=c&newstyle=true

The server send back a response (in the above it's all tags containing "c") and client side JavaScript (jQuery actually) is parsing the result and displaying the tags in the design you are familiar with.

You can see it happening by opening the "network" tab in the developer tools of the browser, these days all major browsers got one even IE.

Comment: thanks for the answer and and for the `howto answer similar question myself` part(looking at the "network" tab)!

Comment: Cheers, glad to share my knowledge!

Comment: Btw, since tags are more less stable(the list doesn't change much), wouldn't it be better to just send `all tags` now and then, and let clients to search/sort through it?

Comment: @Eugene no, with about 35500 tags it would cause HUGE load on the browser, really no need for such thing.